# It is possible to obtain the tweets of a programatically given Twitter user without , without registering my app on dev.twitter.com?

Tags: android, twitter

i need to achieve that, show the last tweets of a programatically given user.

But i need to do it without login on twitter, and without using Oauth, **and without registering my app on dev.twitter.com**

It is possible? i can't find the way to do it :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Rest api for this is:GET https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?include_entities=true&include_rts=true&screen_name=&count=2

more on it [here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/user_timeline). It supports authentication and without authentication, it returns public tweets.

Comment: i'm checking your links. can i do it with this method without registering my app on dev.twitter.com???

Comment: i'm reading the documentation, i check what is screen_name but i dont understand it. Why you put that value for screen name? From with user is giving that url his tweets???  Sorry for my bad skills, i'm trying to improve them

Comment: amazing, you are just amazing, your code works: https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?include_entities=true&include_rts=true&screen_name=charliesheen&count=2

Comment: Please, mate, can you give me the link where you find that solution? i can't find on twitter dev websive, and i need to find the website to understand the solucion and check for updates in the future

Comment: Oh, the info is here: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/user_timeline    one more time, thanks mate!